# Программирование сайта

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток! Интересует вопрос применения php на сайте. Я разделил сайт на подключаемые блоки при помощи include, далее сделаю вывод навигации, новостей, постраничной навигации, форму обратной связи, реализую поиск по сайту. Правильно ли я делаю? Что еще можно сделать/улучшить? И проблема в том что у меня горы php кода прямо в html, можно ли это как то исправить/унифицировать.

Comment: от Вашего вопроса я понял что Вы новичок на этом сфере. Если я правильно понял то для начало это нормально. Почти все начинают программировать с этом этапом. Но для написать код с профессиональном подходам, советую вам изучать создания пользовательская функции, потом реализовать Ваше сайт с функциями, и поэтапно изучать объектно ориентированный программирования и теперь реализуем сайт по подходам ООП. Есть ещё понятия MVC. После того можете изучать Фреймворки(это может быть Codeigniter, Laravel, Yii и т.д.) И в конце Вы становитесь профессиональный программист!!!

Comment: Всем, кто задает этот вопрос, я рекомендую статью [Symfony2 против чистого PHP](http://symfony-gu.ru/documentation/ru/html/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html). Совсем не обязательно после ее прочтения начинать использовать Симфони, но она объясняет, почему любой фреймворк лучше

Answer (score 1):

Используй framework'и Yii,  Phalcon и т.п. (их огромное множество). Помогут разграничить логику от представления, да и с базой работать попроще будет.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Логику отделяй от представления. Smarty или Twig в помощь, остальные шаблонизаторы не юзал.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?